# AWS ECS WaitUntilTasksRunningWithContext returning ResourceNotReady

Tags: go, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk-go

I'm not very proficient with Go but seeing the following error while waiting for an ECS task to start:

> error waiting AWS ECS Task "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:123456789012:task/ecs-cluster/22452be490a149e781a596a7847dd27c" to be in "Running" state: ResourceNotReady: failed waiting for successful resource state

The task being started has a launch type of EC2. Sometimes it will start, but fairly regularly it will return that error.

We get that while doing:

```
input := ecs.DescribeTasksInput{
        Cluster: &cluster,
        Tasks:   []*string{&taskARN},
    }

    err = a.ecsSvc.WaitUntilTasksRunningWithContext(ctx, &input)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf(`error waiting AWS Fargate Task %q to be in "Running" state: %w`, taskARN, err)
    }
```

What would be the better solution here? To send in a custom WaiterOption to `WaitUntilTasksRunningWithContext` or to rather just retry the method if we get this failure?

For additional context. When checking in the console, I can see the task running, so this is most probably a case of `WaitUntilTasksRunningWithContext` returning too quickly.

If a retry is a good option, how would that look like?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because I'm not a `go` developer, but where is `WaitUntilTasksRunningWithContext` defined? I don't see it here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ecs In other AWS SDKs I believe you can pass a timeout setting to waiters. You either need to add a longer timeout, or you need to wrap it in a loop and only break out with an error after the 2nd or 3rd wait fails.